# The LINQ expression DbSet<User> could not be translated

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I've seen a lot of people posting questions similar to this one but I can't seem to find one that answers mine. I'm trying to do a search on users based on either first or last name, email, or login name and I get the error when searching based in any field. I've read that you can't use custom functions inside the `.Where` portion of the queries but does that also include the built in EF ones? I'm very new to .NET and Entity Framework so any suggestions and help is greatly appreciated. I'll post some code below for reference.

Error Message

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'The LINQ expression 'DbSet<User>
    .Where(u => True)
    .Where(u => False || __Functions_0
        .ILike(
            _: u.FirstName, 
            matchExpression: __Format_1))' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync(). See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.'
```

```
 public Task<UserSearchRsModel> Handle(UserSearchRqModel request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
 {
     var users = Filter(request, Context.Users);
     var userCount = users.Count(); <-- **(Error occurs here)**

     users = Sort(/*request.Sort,*/ users);
     users = Page(request.Page, users);

     return Task.FromResult(new UserSearchRsModel(
                _autoMapper.Map<List<User>, List<UserRsModel>>(users.ToList()),
                userCount));
 }


 private IQueryable<User> Filter(UserSearchRqModel request, IQueryable<User> users)
 {
      return users.Where(x => !request.HasLoginName || EF.Functions.ILike(x.LoginName, $"%{request.LoginName}%"))
                  .Where(x => !request.HasFirstName || EF.Functions.ILike(x.FirstName, $"%{request.FirstName}%"))
                  .Where(x => !request.HasLastName || EF.Functions.ILike(x.LastName, $"%{request.LastName}%"))
                  .Where(x => !request.HasEmail || EF.Functions.ILike(x.Email, $"%{request.Email}%"));

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
  return users.Where(x => (!request.HasLoginName ||x.LoginName.Contains(request.LoginName))
                          || (!request.HasFirstName ||x.FirstName.Conatins(equest.FirstName))
                          ||  (!request.HasLastName || x.LastName.Conatins(request.LastName))
                          || ( !request.HasEmail || x.Email.Contains(request.Email)));
```

The way you had your where clause setup, it was going to do `where` `x && y && z`
now it will do `x || y || z`

Comment: That makes sense, but Contains doesn't exist in the current context.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to refactor the query and am no longer getting errors

```
return users.Where(x => (!request.HasLoginName || x.LoginName.ToLower().Contains(request.LoginName))
                   && (!request.HasFirstName || x.FirstName.ToLower().Contains(request.FirstName))
                   && (!request.HasLastName || x.LastName.ToLower().Contains(request.LastName))
                   && (!request.HasEmail || x.Email.ToLower().Contains(request.Email)));
```